# Conversion of date-time data

Tags: stata

Managed to answer the question, though not by using 'help datetime' (already did that) or by reading N.Cox's 'Speaking Stata: On numbers and strings'.
Solution:

```
gen dob_ymd_nn = date(dob_ymd,"DMYhm")
format dob_ymd_nn %td
```

Thank you

My Stata variable `dob_dmy` shows date of birth of participant. Database unfortunately added time (all read 00:00). It is currently a string variable `(str16)`. When I sort, it sorts not on the date but first on the day. See below

```
63. | 01/01/1975 00:00 |
64. | 01/01/1985 00:00 |
65. | 01/02/2010 00:00 |
```

I would like to drop the time and change format that will allow me to sort by actual date.

Comment: I would suggest reading at least `help datetime` and post back if you have trouble with code.

Comment: The original title "Thoroughly looked on this site, Stata site, University sites. Lots found but not relevant to my query or did not work" would be useless to anyone else at indicating your precise question. Please choose informative titles.

Comment: The solution you mention **is** documented in the help you mention. The 2002 article you cite does not purport to discuss dates systematically and in any event could not possibly discussing handling of date-times, which were introduced to Stata in 2007.

Answer (score 1):

@Stan indicated the main idea, that you must convert from a string to a numeric date variable. @Roberto Ferrer underlined that this is all documented prominently within Stata itself. No internet search is needed.

Using your data as a sandbox (you can create such yourself easily in future questions using `dataex` (SSC)) and taking the hint in the variable name that the dates run day, month, year, then we can just ignore the useless time of day with `substr()` and pass the useful stuff to `daily()`. Add a date `format` for readability and then `sort`ing works as desired.

```
. clear

. input str16 sdate 

                sdate
  1. "01/02/2010 00:00"
  2. "01/01/1985 00:00"
  3. "01/01/1975 00:00"
  4. end 

. gen ddate = daily(substr(sdate, 1, 10), "DMY") 

. format ddate %td

. sort ddate 

. list 

     +------------------------------+
     |            sdate       ddate |
     |------------------------------|
  1. | 01/01/1975 00:00   01jan1975 |
  2. | 01/01/1985 00:00   01jan1985 |
  3. | 01/02/2010 00:00   01feb2010 |
     +------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're storing dates as strings in MM/DD/YYYY format, you won't be able to sort them, except by month, then day, then year (which isn't very helpful).  You need to convert them to dates, and THEN sort them.

From the following link:

```
gen date_obs = clock(datetime_obs, "MD20Yhm") //Obvously you have 4 digit years, so would change this to "MDYhm"
format date_obs %tc
```

http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2013-08/msg01434.html

Comment: Unfortunately it is essential to specify a `double` to hold date-times precisely. See `help dates`.